# How to detect a SQL Server database's read-only status using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, readonly

I need to know how to interrogate a Microsoft SQL Server, to see if a given database has been set to `Read-Only` or not.

Is that possible, using T-SQL?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The information is stored in `sys.databases`.

```
SELECT name, is_read_only 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'MyDBNAme'
GO

--returns 1 in is_read_only when database is set to read-only mode.
```

Answer (score 43):

Querying `sys.databases` for checking a DB's Read-Only property will **only** give the right information if the database has been **explicitly** set to Read-Only mode.

For databases that are in the passive servers (e.g. in AlwaysOn technology Secondary Servers), even though the databases cannot be written into, their Read-Only mode in `sys.databases` would still be set as `False(0)`.

Hence, it is advisable to check the Read-Only mode of databases using the statement:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDBNAme', 'Updateability');
```

Comment: This worked for me as well to check for Primary vs Secondary on an Azure Database.  Of note, the values returned are READ_ONLY and READ_WRITE.  Also, in Azure, if you query from a database that does not match the database name passed into the first parameter, the result will be NULL.

Comment: So this works well on Azure: SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability');

Comment: Useful to add the server name to the script, for when you're trying it on several servers `SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('(databasename)', 'Updateability') AS Status;`

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to use the p.campbell's answer to check if my Azure SQL DB is the primary one or the read only replica - it didn't work. Both the primary DB and the replica returned had 0 on the is_read_only field.

Here's what worked for me:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDBNAme', 'Updateability');
```

the above select statement returns string 'READ_ONLY' or 'READ_WRITE'.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933268%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to display or set this property.

```
EXEC sp_dboption "AdventureWorks", "read only"
```

**Sample output**

```
OptionName CurrentSetting    
read only OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

If DB is part of your Always On and the secondary node is designed in Read_Only then
"sys.databases --> Is_Read_Only" column wont show the correct result ! its a bug that Microsoft needs to address it during the next versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check all DB statuses in your server, use this:

```
SELECT name, user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc  
FROM sys.databases;
```

You can quickly determine your next steps.