# How to verify if OdbcConnection is read only?

Tags: c#, database

I'm having an open OdbcConnection, I'm trying to write to a database using OdbcCommand and I would like to verify if the database i read-only before inserting data.

I can use try and catch, but I hope there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DSN=SERVER1;UID=User;PWD=User");
try
{    
    con.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Test', 100)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close()
}
```

Here's the output when the database is read-only:

> ERROR [HY000] SOLID Database Error 10013: Transaction is read-only

Comment: That depends on the database. For SQL Server, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2930251/11683.

Comment: So the question is not is odbcconnection readonly, it's is the database table read only?

Comment: Paul Zahra - yep that is what I want to know. I just tought I could get the information form the odbcconnection :)

Answer (score 0):

For sql server you can use :
The information is stored in sys.databases.

```
SELECT name, is_read_only 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'MyDBNAme'
GO
```

--returns 1 in is_read_only when database is set to read-only mode.

for oracle db you can use OPEN_MODE property to check.